# Restricting a column value to predefined List of strings

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to predefine the the possible values of a column in mysql.

for example the column `Fruits` can  have values `apple, orange, mango` as individual values or can have as a list like `apple,orange`,`apple,mango` etc.

```
eg:
    juice       fruites
    ---------------------
    j1          'mango'
    j2          'mango,apple'
    j3          'apple,orange'
    j4          'apple'
    ....etc
```

I could find `check constraints` or `Enum` to serve this purpose is there any better way to accomplish the same?

as I may want to add some more elements to this list say `grapes` in future, so the method i use now must be extensive.

So kindly suggest which is the best way, or if i have to use `constraint` or `Enum` which among them is better, in terms of easiness to extend as well.

Comment: if the enum as` ('apple', 'orange','apple,orange','mango','apple,mango','orange,mango','apple,orange,mango‌​')`,  leaves a great difficulty to add a new one. also when an enum option is made as `'apple,orange'` if user enter `'orange, apple'` it fails,

Answer (score 1):

> I could find check constraints or Enum to serve this purpose is there any better way to accomplish the same?

Yes, normalize your database with a link-table:

```
 juice
 id | name
  1   j1
  2   j2

 fruit
 id | name
 1    mango
 2    apple

 juices_fruits
 juice_id | fruit_id
 1          1
 2          1
 2          2
```

With a proper foreign key constraint (*juice_id references juice.id and fruit_id references fruit.id*), you can only insert "valid" fruits into the `juices_fruits` table. Additional you can use a unique_key constraint on *juice_id, fruit_id* to ensure that no fruit is added twice to the same juice.

To Query this, you can use `group_concat` to get a comma-seperated list:

```
SELECT j.name, GROUP_CONCAT(f.name) FROM
  juice j
LEFT JOIN
  juices_fruits jf
on
  jf.juice_id = j.id
LEFT JOIN
  fruit f
ON
  jf.fruit_id = f.id
GROUP BY
  j.id;
```

Result:

```
j1 | mango
j2 | mango,apple
```

Comment: That is really nice suggestion to create an m to n mapping by creating a third table, if i understand it correct. My requirement is not that huge to create a 3 table structure. i had thought about this, but couldn't do this. but thanks anyways. –  manoj

Answer (score 0):

"The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines."

This leaves `ENUM`'s and triggers as your only options.

`ENUM`'s have the benefit of being a little bit faster (because they only store up to 2 bytes of data), but altering them can take longer.

With a trigger you can define whatever constraints you want, and also you can have custom errors when the constraint fails. Altering them doesn't depend on the amount of data in the table.

Comment: should i be defining the enum as `('apple', 'orange','apple,orange','mango','apple,mango','orange,mango','apple,orange,mango')`  this leaves a great difficulty to add a new one. also when an enum option is made as `'apple,orange'`  if user enter `'orange, apple'` it fails, so is there a way to have list of enums or enum array as a type of a column ?

Comment: You can try a [SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html) type, but in this case a separate table (one to many relation) would probably be better because searching for apples in a set (or plain csv) field can't use indexes. Also SET fields are limited to 64 options.